# Bulk Cropping Images Manually

Tags: linux, open-source, image-editor

I'm looking for a program:

- That is gratis and open-source
- That runs on Linux (and preferably also on Windows)
- Where I can open a directory of images (JPG or PNG)
- Where I can select the part to be cropped
- Where I can press one key to crop it and move on to the next image
- Where I can press one key to delete the image

Comment: Not sure, but IrfanView might suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to bulk crop or manually crop? Your question sounds like you are looking to manually crop each image based on the area you select rather than bulk crop based on a pre-defined area.

If it's the former, you could try Phatch, or read through the following https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20632/how-to-record-action-for-automatic-repeat-in-gimp

Comment: I need to quickly crop (or delete) ±400 images manually.